# consecutive statements on a line must be separated by '; ' swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, xcode8

Hello I'm trying to make an app that will convert human years into cat years and i am having some trouble with the button that you tap to show the cat year.

```
@IBAction func findAge(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    var enteredAge = age.text
    var myInt: 13 = int(enteredAge)
    var catYears = enteredAge * 7
    print(age.text) 
}
```

on `var myInt: 13 = int(enteredAge)` I get 2 errors one is the title of this question and the other says "expected type" I am currently running xcode 8 beta.

Comment: var myInt: 13 ???? 13 is not a type

Comment: This is not the only issue here. You also have a logic problem (using the wrong variables). Oh, and Optionals too... // I strongly suggest you read the Swift language guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Answer (score 2):

`var myInt : Int = Int(enteredAge)`
The `;` error is very unhelpful in swift debugging, but as El Captain pointed out, the info following `:` in Swift should be an Object Type.

Comment: I'm not very experienced this is actually my first project so if you could go into showing me what i should do with it to make it work because i have tried everything and nothing i do seems to help

Comment: `nothing i do seems to help` What would help is to *read the Swift manual*. I've already given you the link.

Comment: The line I gave you solves the error you posted. As Eric said, you'll need to read up. In addition to the Swift manual, Google or StackOverflow-search each question as you have it - most are already answered on here somewhere.

Comment: I'm watching this guide or whatever from Udemy just that i think it's expired but i already got it and I don't wanna feel like i wasted money. thanks for the link

Comment: @Gh0st Beware of the [sunk costs fallacy](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/tools/lp/Bo/LogicalFallacies/173/Sunk_Cost_Fallacy)... If you bought a bad/obsolete tutorial, just let it go. :) Anyway, please study the document I linked, there's *everything* you need to know about Swift in it.

Answer (score 1):

There is several problems in your code ... (casting , check for optionals) ... so all and all there is some logic problem here .. .here is some work around

```
if let enteredAge = age.text, myInt = Int(enteredAge) {
     //... success...
     let catYears = myInt * 7  // myInt gives you Int value , enteredAge returns String 
     print(catYears)
}
else{
     //.... handle nil  ....  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to say you should read what El Captain and Eric D have said already.

To answer your question, the line:

```
var myInt: 13 = int(enteredAge)
```

Should be:

```
var myInt = Int(enteredAge)
```

That will get rid of your warning. However, there is some clear logical issues which can be solved [in many ways, but most simply] like this:

```
@IBAction func findAge(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let enteredAge = age.text
    let myInt = Int(enteredAge)
    let catYears = myInt * 7
    print(catYears) 
}
```